# PHP extension Dio is not loaded?

Tags: php, php-extension

I am trying to communicate with the COM Ports using the DIO extension, but it's not working it seems. I have already added the .dll file into my ext folder but I still can't find the Dio support enabled in PHP info(). I have already restarted my XAMPP server more than twice, but still, it's not working. This is my current code for the com port testing.

```
    $portName = 'COM9:';
    $baudRate = 9600;
    $bits = 8;
    $spotBit = 1;

    header( 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' ); 
    ?>
    Serial Port Test
    ================
<?php


function echoFlush($string)
{
    echo $string . "\n";
    flush();
    ob_flush();
}

if(!extension_loaded('dio'))
{
    echoFlush( "PHP Direct IO does not appear to be installed for more info see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dio.php" );
    exit;
}
```

This is the error I am getting now.

```
PHP Direct IO does not appear to be installed for more info see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dio.php
```

This is the steps I followed while installing the extension:

1. I downloaded the direct io from the [pecl website](http://pecl.php.net/package/dio/0.0.7/windows)
2. Then I copied the `php_dio.dll` into the PHP/ext folder
3. Next, I edited the `php.ini` file by adding the `extension=php_dio.dll`
4. Then I restarted my XAMPP webserver
5. I opened `php_info()` to check out the `php_dio.dll` and found that it is not still loaded.

Comment: The error message suggests that the installation of DIO is incomplete or broken. Since this is a [PECL extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/dio), have you looked at their [installation documentation](https://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php)?

Comment: @FriendFX yes i have looked at the installation documentation before installing the DIO extension. I downloaded the [link]http://pecl.php.net/package/dio/0.0.7/windows correct version for my XAMPP windows webserver, but still its not working.

Comment: It could be that it was trying to [install into the wrong directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15359694/897968), for example. Or you [need to modify your php.ini](https://www.drupal.org/node/456686#comment-1719686). If you edit your question to add what you have tried so far (exact steps if possible), it will be more likely that people may recognise the source of the problem.

Comment: @FriendFX i have already edited my question as you said

Comment: Did you manage to establish a communication thru the rs-232 port?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check `extension_dir` directive in your `phpinfo()` output?

Answer (score 1):

Try using PHP version 7.2, it works for me, but not in version 7.3.

Answer (score 0):

We got confused with the XAMPP architecture version with Windows. It worked after installing the right. Thank you guys.